# Cannot load abbreviations with siunitx v2

Tags: siunitx, mactex

I use MacTeX, and the current distribution comes with `siunitx` v2 (`\ProvidesExplPackage {siunitx} {2020/02/25} {2.8b}`). I would like to use units such as `\ms` and `\hertz` which require the abbreviations package. I load it with `\sisetup{load=abbr}`, but it seems to be v1 code and I get this warning:

`Package siunitx Warning: Version 1 option 'load' detected`

I tried the following code: `\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}`, but my code does not work anymore, the `\ms` and `\hertz` are undefined.

Now I can only find the documentation for v3. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a warning, not an error: the loading will be fine. For v2, `load-configurations = abbreviations` is a load-only option, so you want

```latex
\usepackage[load-configurations = abbreviations]{siunitx}
```

(The option is set `true` as-standard in v2, so you shouldn't need to use it at all.)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, support, and the great package! I knew it is only a warning but I like to have a clean output. I managed to get it to work without the option. The reason it wasn't working initially without the option was that I write `\si{250}{\hertz}` instead of `\SI{250}{\hertz}`. This was the real issue, but your answer is definitely useful. Thanks!